# How to properly join data and geometry using ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

An image is worth a thousand words:
[image: Data does not match geometry]

**Observed behaviour:** As can be seen from the image above, countries' names do not match with their actual geometries.

**Expected behaviour:** I would like to properly join a data frame with its geometry and display the result in ggmap.

I've previously joined different data frames, but things get wrong by the fact that apparently `ggmap` needs to "fortify" (actually I don't know what really means) data frame in order to display results.

**This is what I've done so far:**

```
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(ggmap)

# Load GeoJSON file with countries.
countries = readOGR(dsn = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ccamara/fc26d8bb7e777488b446fbaad1e6ea63/raw/a6f69b6c3b4a75b02858e966b9d36c85982cbd32/countries.geojson")

# Load dataframe.
df = read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ccamara/fc26d8bb7e777488b446fbaad1e6ea63/raw/a6f69b6c3b4a75b02858e966b9d36c85982cbd32/sample-dataframe.csv")

# Join geometry with dataframe.
countries$iso_a2 = as.factor(countries$iso_a2)
countries@data = left_join(countries@data, df, by = c('iso_a2' = 'country_code'))

# Convert to dataframe so it can be used by ggmap.
countries.t = tidy(countries)

# Here's where the problem starts, as by doing so, data has been lost!

# Recover attributes' table that was destroyed after using broom::tidy.
countries@data$id = rownames(countries@data) # Adding a new id variable.
countries.t = left_join(countries.t, countries@data, by = "id")

ggplot(data = countries.t,
       aes(long, lat, fill = country_name, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  geom_path(colour="black", lwd=0.05) + # polygon borders
  coord_equal() +
  ggtitle("Data and geometry have been messed!") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), # change the theme options
        axis.title = element_blank(), # remove axis titles
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) # remove axis ticks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason for the messed up behaviour.

`countries` starts out as a large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with **177** elements (and correspondingly 177 rows in `countries@data`). When you perform `left_join` on `countries@data` and `df`, the number of elements in `countries` isn't affected, but the number of rows in `countries@data` grows to **210**.

Fortifying `countries` using `broom::tidy` converts `countries`, with its 177 elements, into a data frame with `id` running from 0 to 176. (I'm not sure why it's zero-indexed, but I usually prefer to specify the regions explicitly anyway).

Adding `id` to `countries@data` based on `rownames(countries@data)`, on the other hand, results in `id` values running from 1 to 210, since that's the number of rows in `countries@data` after the earlier join with `df`. Consequently, everything is out of sync.

Try the following instead:

```
# (we start out right after loading countries & df)

# no need to join geometry with df first

# convert countries to data frame, specifying the regions explicitly
# (note I'm using the name column rather than the iso_a2 column from countries@data;
# this is because there are some repeat -99 values in iso_a2, and we want
# one-to-one matching.)
countries.t = tidy(countries, region = "name")

# join with the original file's data
countries.t = left_join(countries.t, countries@data, by = c("id" = "name"))

# join with df
countries.t = left_join(countries.t, df, by = c("iso_a2" = "country_code"))

# no change to the plot's code, except for ggtitle
ggplot(data = countries.t,
       aes(long, lat, fill = country_name, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  geom_path(colour="black", lwd = 0.05) +
  coord_equal() +
  ggtitle("Data and geometry are fine") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

p.s. You don't actually need the ggmap package for this. Just the ggplot2 package that it loads.

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation! Your solution works great! There's something I do not understand though (even after having checked `?broom::tidy`): It seems to me that the statement `countries.t = tidy(countries, region = "name")` is key in your answer, but I do not understand what `region="name"` exactly does, despite I have observed notable differences in the output if I just type `countries.t = tidy(countries)`

Comment: And thanks for pointing out that ggmap is not needed for these matters. I wanted to do some more things, though, but everything relies on fixing this issue ;)

Comment: @ccamara As per `?broom::sp_tidy.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, the `region` argument specifies the name of the variable from `countries@data` to be used to split up regions.

Comment: If `region` is unspecified, each row of `countries@data` is treated as a separate region, and `countries.t$id` takes on the values 0-176 (based on row number of `countries@data` - 1). If you specify `region = "name"`, each group of rows with a different `countries@data$name` value is treated as a separate region, and `countries.t$id` takes on the values of country names. This allows us to join `countries.t` with other data frames by country name, rather than depend on matching the original row numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I could not find that information (or understand it) in the command's built-in help. Much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

While your work is a reasonable approach - I would like to rethink your design, mainly because of two simple reasons:

1) while GeoJSON is the future, R still heavily relies on the sp package and its correspondent sp* objects - very soon you wish you had switched early on. It`s just about the packages and most of them (if not all) rely on sp* objects.

2) ggplot has great plotting capabilities combined with ggmap - but its still quite limited compared to sp* in combination with leaflet for R etc.

probably the fastest way to go is simple as:

```
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(geojsonio)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

#get sp* object instead of geojson
countries <- geojsonio::geojson_read("foo.geojson",what = "sp")

#match sp* object with your data.frame
countries@data <- dplyr::left_join(countries@data, your_df, by = 
c("identifier_1" = "identifier_2"))

#creates a fast and nice looking plot / lots of configuration available
p1 <- tm_shape(countries) +
      tm_polygons() 
p1

#optional interactive leaflet plot
tmap_leaflet(p1)
```

It is written out of my head / bear with me if there are minor issues.

It is a different approach but its at least in my eyes a faster and more concise approach in R right now (hopefully geojson will receive more support in the future).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently testing options and tmap is indeed a good choice. In fact it was my first one, but I ended up with this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298066/tmap-error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y (I think I am doing the same approach as you did) and that's why I ended trying ggmap (that and the lack of option of adding a map's title!).  

By the way, there's something I do not understand about your answer: what do you mean by sp* objects? are there some R-object types?

Comment: read the documentation of the "sp" package - from start to nearly end. It is easy to read and will give you a proper overview how to deal with spatial data. Afterwards everything seems half as hard as it used to be.