# Tmap Error - replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]

Tags: r, tmap

**Short version:** when executing the following command `qtm(countries, "freq")` I get the following error message:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "SHAPE_AREAS", value =
>   c(652270.070308042,  :    replacement has 177 rows, data has 210

**Disclaimer:** I have already checked other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145533/r-message-error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y) as well as [this explanation](https://www.r-bloggers.com/translating-weird-r-errors/) that states that usually this error comes from misspelling objects, but could not find an answer to my problem.

**Reproducible code:**

```
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

# Load JSON file with countries.
countries = readOGR(dsn = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ccamara/fc26d8bb7e777488b446fbaad1e6ea63/raw/a6f69b6c3b4a75b02858e966b9d36c85982cbd32/countries.geojson")

# Load dataframe.
df = read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ccamara/fc26d8bb7e777488b446fbaad1e6ea63/raw/754ea37e4aba1b7ed88eaebd2c75fd4afcc54c51/sample-dataframe.csv")


countries@data = left_join(countries@data, df, by = c("iso_a2" = "country_code"))

qtm(countries, "freq")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the data - the code works fine.

What you are doing right now is:

1) attempting a 1:1 match

2) realize that your .csv data contains several ids to match

3) a left-join then multiplies the left hand side with all matches on the right hand-side

To avoid this issue you have to aggregate your data one more time like:

```
library(dplyr)

df_unique = df %>%
    group_by(country_code, country_name) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(total), freq = sum(freq))


#after that you should be fine - as long as just adding up the data is okay.
countries@data = left_join(countries@data, df, by = c("iso_a2" = 
"country_code"))

qtm(countries, "freq")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the answer. It is now working!

Comment: I'm afraid that, despite I thought I had understood what my problem was (having one variable on the left dataframe that matched several variables on the right one, and hence, I needed to group variables on right dataframe) I am facing the same message again, but I'm pretty sure that the problem is another one. If you were so kind to answer, I posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430561/tmap-error-when-joining-dataframe-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y . sorry if I'm asking too much @Christian